# Python - Cambiar formato de fecha "2019-01-29T17:48:48-03:00" ISO-8601 a dateformat

Tags: python, django

Estoy tratando de cambiar el formato de fecha que obtengo de una aplicación: `2019-01-29T17:48:48-03:00` a poder manejarlo como un objeto o una lista y darle un formato propio, pero no logro conseguirlo.

Quiero pasar de esto `2019-01-29T17:48:48-03:00` a esto `29/01/2019`

Comment: @fredyfx No es un duplicado exacto,el formato de la cadena de entrada tiene un offset horario que causa problemas nuevos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque para manipular fechas siempre la mejor opción es convertirlas a objetos de tipo `datetime`, lo cual te permite después calcular distancias entre fechas, convertirlas a cadena con cualquier formato que necesites, etc. si en este caso particular todo lo que requieres es convertir la cadena `"2019-01-29T17:48:48-03:00"` en `"29/01/2019"`, puedes aplicar operaciones de cadena.

Por ejemplo:

```
fecha = "2019-01-29T17:48:48-03:00"
partes = fecha.split("T")[0].split("-")
convertida = "/".join(reversed(partes))
```

donde divido la cadena por la `"T"`, me quedo con la primera parte (`[0]`), y ésta la divido otra vez por los guiones, lo que me da una lista con los elementos año, mes y día. Invierto la lista y concateno de nuevo sus elementos con un `/` como separador.

Resultado:

```
'29/01/2019'
```

### Edito

Si necesitas convertir tu cadena en `datetime` no necesitas en principio instalar ningún módulo extra. El módulo `datetime.datetime` contiene la función `strptime()` que es capaz de interpretar cadenas conteniendo fechas y horas en muchos formatos diferentes, incluyendo *timezones* y *offsets horarios*.

Por desgracia la que tú muestras causa un problema en la parte del offset horario. Entiendo que lo que aparece al final tras el `-`, es decir, lo de `03:00`,  es un offset horario. La forma habitual de representarlos es sin los dos puntos, o sea `-0300`. A partir de Python 3.7, éste admite que aparezcan dos puntos como en tu caso ( `-03:00`), pero para versiones anteriores no.

No obstante podemos eliminar esos dos puntos del final usando `rsplit(":",1)` (que divide la cadena por el primer `":"` que encuentre desde el final), y reagrupando el resultado con `"".join()`, así:

```
fecha_aux = "".join(fecha.rsplit(":", 1))
```

Una vez hecho esto, puede convertirse ya a objeto `datetime` así:

```
import datetime.datetime
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha_aux, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
```

El segundo parámetro le dice cómo interpretar tu fecha, es decir, qué parte es el año, el mes, el día, la hora, el minuto, el segundo, y el offset horario. Una vez lo tienes convertido en `datetime` puedes manipularlo de muchas formas, por ejemplo imprimirlo en cualquier otro formato, usando `strftime()`

```
print(dstrftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

---

```
29/01/2019
```

Como dije antes, si sólo querías convertir la cadena, puedes usar otro tipo de funciones Python de manejo de cadenas. Pero tenerlo convertido en `datetime` puede ser necesario para otras tareas.

Answer (score 1):

`2019-01-29T17:48:48-03:00` esta en formato ISO-8601 y la manera de parsear ese formato de fecha es el siguiente:

Instalar: `pip install python-dateutil`

En el código:

```
fecha = "2019-01-29T17:48:48-03:00"
fecha = dateutil.parser.parse(fecha)
fecha = fecha.strftime('%d / $m / %Y') // Para dar formato
```

Respuesta obtenida desde:

### https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date